# WordPress - Need help writing a second function to modify the_excerpt

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code in my `functions.php` that takes the first `<p>` of a post and spits it out as my excerpt

```
function awesome_excerpt($text, $raw_excerpt) {
        if( ! $raw_excerpt ) {
            $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );
            $text = substr( $content, 0, strpos( $content, '</p>' ) + 4 );
        }
        $text = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $text); 
        return $text;
    }
    add_filter( 'wp_trim_excerpt', 'awesome_excerpt', 10, 2 );
```

I have a second function, I watched a video where this got the excerpt with a character count. Thing is, in the video it was `the_excerpt`.

```
// Customize Excerpt Word Count Length
    function custom_excerpt_length() {
        return 25;
    }
    add_filter('excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length');
```

I called it like this:

```
<?php echo custom_excerpt_length(); ?>
```

On the front-end it spat out 25, so something is wrong in my function.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to set a priority for your length like this : 
`add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );`

Comment: I tried that, 'the_excerpt' spat out nothing. I'm thinking the other excerpt is messing with it.

Comment: check this topic, it may help you : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/139953/excerpt-length-not-working

Comment: Ah, feel free to mark this as a duplicate then, yes this worked!

Comment: Well i can't it's on stackexchange ^^

Comment: There's actually one slight issue. This code makes my '<a>' I have after the call included inside of the '<p>' the excerpt prints, I don't want it to do that.